# Много одинаковых кнопок, которые меняют класс одному div

Tags: javascript

Я новичок в js. Столкнулся с проблемой.
Есть много одинаковых кнопок на одной странице, которые убирают класс в одном div.
Но срабатывает только первая. Остальные не работают.
Подскажите как сделать правильно?

Кнопка:

```
<a id="forma-lang">Заказать&nbsp;перевод</a>
```

div который меняет класс:

```
<div id="shop" class="no-display">
```

И код js:

```
document.getElementById('forma-lang').onclick = function() { document.getElementById('shop').classList.toggle('no-display');
```

}

Comment: А где остальные кнопки?

Comment: Все кнопки на одной странице.
Все на одной странице.
Все одинаковые : <a id="forma-lang">Заказать&nbsp;перевод</a>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну начнём с того, что один конкретный id может быть только у одного элемента на странице, а т.к. у тебя много одинаковых кнопок, то id у кнопок следует заменить на class. И получаем вот такой код:

```
<a class="forma-lang">Заказать&nbsp;перевод</a>


document.querySelectorAll(".forma-lang").forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener("click", ()=>{document.getElementById('shop').classList.toggle('no-display')})
})
```

Comment: "А слона и не заметил". Спасибо большое!